# run a meteor app on docker - doesn't open in localhost

Tags: meteor, docker

i am pretty new to docker...
i am trying to run my meteor app on a docker container using meteorD,
it seems to successes.
when i run 
`docker ps`
i get this:
`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
fd681d515a09        abernix/meteord:base   "/bin/sh -c 'bash $ME"   57 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   app-web`
 
but-
 when i open **0.0.0.0:8080** in my browser
i get this meesage:
`This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8080/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.`
cant figure what am i missing ...
thanks for any help
fay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0.0.0.0 usually means all ip address on your local machine.

If you're running docker natively, try:

- http://localhost:8080
- http://127.0.0.1:8080

If you're using docker-machine/boot2docker (such as using Docker Toolbox), try retrieving your vm ip by using:

`docker-machine ip default`

and substitute 0.0.0.0 with the returned value, such as:

- http://192.168.0.1:8080